# Trying to get IE8 CSS float:top (I know no such thing exist)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to display this to left --

```
<div id="imageWrap">
          <img id="bigpic" src="pictures/3inchBinders/3inLarge.jpg" 
          height="200" width="175" alt="3 inch Binder" />
</div>
```

This will be right under imageWrap

```
<div class="thumbnail-wrapper" align="justify">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-index="0">
                    <img height="75" width="75" 
                            src="pictures/other/backSide.JPG" /></a>           
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-index="1">
                    <img height="75" width="75" 
                            src="pictures/other/underSide.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-index="2">
                    <img height="75" width="75" 
                            src="pictures/other/open180logoTwo.jpg" /></a> 
                </div>
```

All that works how I need it, but with a major gap in between the two... I also have stats about the binders that need to be just to the right of the imageWrap, and thumbnail wrapper. This is my issue, since I can't align top I tried using -10em for margin and padding but nothing works.

How can I get this to display more properly?

Comment: not completely sure what you need here, can you show the css youve currently written?

Comment: do you have a screenshot of how it is and another of how you would like it along with the current css. maybe make a fiddle

Comment: no real need to downvote someone new to the SO